# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bitmap' of undefined (ApostropheCMS)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

When trying to upload any GIF file , a weird error happen. This error came out :

```
Unsupported MIME type: image/gif
Unsupported MIME type: image/gif
Unsupported MIME type: image/gif
Unsupported MIME type: image/gif
Unsupported MIME type: image/gif
Unsupported MIME type: image/gif
Unsupported MIME type: image/gifUnsupported MIME type: image/gif
Unsupported MIME type: image/gifUnsupported MIME type: image/gif
C:\Users\Azmin\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\uploadfs\lib\image\jimp.js:46        var originalWidth = image.bitmap.width;
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bitmap' of undefined
    at Jimp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Azmin\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\uploadfs\lib\image\jimp.js:46:35)
    at Jimp.throwError (C:\Users\Azmin\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\jimp\index.js:85:44)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\Azmin\Desktop\amin-website\node_modules\jimp\index.js:201:44)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
```

> Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Via the `uploadfs` module, Apostrophe supports several backends for processing images. By default, you get `jimp`. `jimp` is helpful because it is pure javascript and has no dependencies on system packages, but it is also very slow and the version currently in Apostrophe's uploadfs module has no GIF support.

Upgrading jimp in uploadfs and testing the result would make a great pull request, but there's a better long term solution for you. Apostrophe is only using jimp because it can't find `imagemagick` which is much faster and fully supports GIF.

The solution is to install `imagemagick` in both your dev environment and on your server. This is very easy to do.

In Ubuntu Linux:

`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

In Red Hat-flavored Linux, like CentOS:

`sudo yum install ImageMagick`

In MacOS:

(Install homebrew first if you haven't already. You definitely want homebrew for dev on a mac.)

`brew install imagemagick`

On Windows: [there is an official installer.](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) You will need to make sure to check the box to install the "legacy utilities" like `identify` and `convert`. You will also need to make sure they wind up in your `PATH` so at the command line they can be found (typing `convert` at the cmd prompt should run that imagemagick utility). Then be sure to restart the cmd windows you're testing in to make sure they see that path change.